# Unsupported grant type in flutter get call

Tags: flutter, http, dart

For token refresh I'm using Get Call Rest Api:

```
final queryParameters = {
    'username': 'XXXX',
    'password': 'XXXXX',
    'grant_type': 'password',
  };final uri = Uri.http(baseUrl, AuthTokenUrl, queryParameters);
  var response = await httpClient.get(
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
      uri: uri);
```

Postman body data:

```
username:XXXX password:XXXX grant_type:password
```

But my response is Status code:400 with response as **Unsupported Grant type**.

```
"{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}"
```

I don't know why I'm getting unsupported grant-type in Http get call.In postman everything is working fine.

Any suggestion or solution will be greatly helpful,Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but i was making a post request i had solve it by moving jsonEncode because the data that i had to send to the api must not to be json so in your case you have to check about the data you are getting it is it json from the first place or no